# How can php trigger a 404 error on nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, php

This should be a simple question, but I'm having trouble with it: how can I get php to trigger a 404 error, so that the page the user sees has a true 404 header? I've seen several answers to this, but none have worked for me, maybe because I'm on nginx. I've tried:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

When I've tried each of these (with an exit() afterwards), the server has sent a 200 header.

It seems like this question has been asked in many permutations (Apache / php / sending 404s from the server level, etc) but I'm having trouble finding someone trying to do what I'm trying to do. So, apologies if this is a duplicate - if it is I won't be surprised, and please let me know.

Thank you :) - Katie

Comment: You can have a look here , http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php `If you pass no parameters then http_response_code will get the current status code. If you pass a parameter it will set the response code.`

Comment: The second `header` should work according to the documentation.

Comment: @Shankar - I'm on php 5.3 so that's a no go, looking into alternatives and what it takes to update php.

Comment: @Barmar - I tried it, but it doesn't work - it sends a 200/ok header. Any ideas why that might be? Something to do with php-fpm, or maybe php 5.3?

Comment: Okay, I probably shouldn't update php just for this, probably a little extreme. :) haha - other ideas? (ps, thank you!!)

Comment: Did you try `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");`? ;)

Comment: @Mixthos yep, just tried it and it still returns 200. Thanks though :)

Comment: I just tried it on my nginx server, it worked as expected. http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test404.php

Comment: OK, another wild guess: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404);` A little redundant, but you never know. ;)

Comment: are you sending any data before the headers and have errors turned off?

Comment: @Barmar - could it be an nginx or php-fpm setting I'm missing? Here's the page I'm testing on, right now it's currently using the same code you told me, line 2 above: https://critter.co/skjdfh

Comment: I'm getting `304 Not modified` reply code.

Comment: your page returns data, you say you have exit right after the headers so are you outputting the html before the headers? If so you cant do that you have to send all headers before everything else

Comment: So confused - I'm seeing a 200 code in both Chrome and Safari. Did you maybe catch me while I was trying Mixthos' idea (it was quick but the timing might have been right)? Try now? I won't change it now -

Comment: @Patrick, ah, there's a hint - php isn't returning anything, but it looks like somehow a different page (critter.co/404.shtml, which I've set as the 404 page in nginx) is appending to it. Weird.. I don't understand how php is getting back to nginx without redirecting...

Comment: try turning off that setting and try again

Comment: 404!!! thank you!!! :) I don't understand it but it works now. Thanks, Patrick!! :)

Comment: since php is setting the headers, nginx probably sees that header and says oh im setup to send a page for that header and then just sends the 404.shtml instead of what was output by php. But i cant be sure of that but that is my best guess on why it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked:

Step 1, handle in php:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit();
```

Step 2, Remove nginx error page. I had:

```
error_page 404 = /404.shtml;
```

With the combination of those, 404s are generated as desired.

Thank you, @Barmar and @Patrick Evans for each piece of this solution! :)